# How many different identifiers can a fictitious programming language have?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different identifiers can a fictitious programming language have, when the following rules must be obeyed:

1. Only upper case letters are allowed, so elements of $\{A, ..., Z\}$,
2. The identifier must be at least of length $1$ and at most length $5$.
3. The keywords AND, OR, IF, THEN and GOTO are not allowed to appear in any form in the identifier.

I approached this by looking at the allowed lengths individually and then add all the combinations up.

Length = 1:
Here we simply have only $26$ possibilities.

Length = 2:
This time we have $26^2 - 2$ combinations, since IF and OR can't appear.

Length = 3:
This one is also quite simple. We have $25^3 - 1 - 2*26 - 2*26$ combinations, since AND is not allowed to appear and all combinations that contain IF (IF. and .IF) or OR (OR. and .OR) are invalid.

Length = 4:
This is where I start to have my problems. I tried to do the same thing here, but I am not quite sure. There are $26^4$ total combinations. This time THEN and GOTO can't appear, so $-2$ to accommodate this. AND also can't appear, so $-2*26$. But for IF and OR I am not certain how to calculate it. At first I thought it would simply be $-3*26^2 - 3*26^2$ (IF.. , .IF. , ..IF , OR.. , .OR. , ..OR), but then I thought this would count certain combinations more than once. The combination IFOR for example would be counted twice, so I would have to add $1$ to make up for that. Then there are the combinations IFIF and OROR, which also would be subtracted twice so I would have to add $+1+1$ again. And I am not sure if I missed some of these.

So for Length > 3 I am not quite sure how to tackle this, so I don't miss any combinations and everyone is counted only once.

Comment: What does "appear in any form" mean, exactly?

Comment: According to [disappointingly but usably slow Python](https://repl.it/@JosGibbons/GleefulPuzzlingTutorial#main.py), the answer is $12209994$. Compare this to $\sum_{k=1}^526^k=12356630$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=4$, you also need to add back in `IFOR` and `ORIF`. In other words, all of the doubly subtracted codes look like
$$
AABB, 
$$
where $AA$ and $BB$ are both bad words of length $2$. There are two choices for $AA$, and two choices for $BB$, so you need to add back in $2\times 2$.

When $n=5$, there are more possibilities for doubly subtracted words: they can be
$$
AABB*,\quad AA{*}BB,\quad*AABB,\\
AACCC,\quad CCCAA
$$
Again, $AA$ and $BB$ are arbitrary two-letter bad words, and $CCC$ is an arbitrary three letter bad word (okay, there is only one possibility for $CCC$, but I am trying to show how this will generalize).

That seems to be all the ways to cram two of the bad words into a five letter string. But these are only the ways where the two words do not overlap. Since the end of `GOTO` is the same as the beginning of `OR`, there is one final doubly subtracted word, namely,
$$
GOTOR.
$$
You can check this is the only possibility for overlap. In general, if you had lots of overlapping possibilities, things would be more more complicated. Furthermore, if $n\ge 6$, you would have to worry about triply subtracted words, like `IFOROR`. This problem, however, is quite tractable.

In summary, you initially subtract the words which contain each possible bad word in each possible position, not worrying about double counting, resulting in $$26^5-4\cdot 26^3-4\cdot 26^3-3\cdot 26^2-2\cdot 26-2\cdot 26.$$ But then you must add in all of the doubly subtracted words in the previous paragraphs. For example, for words like $AABB*$, you would add back in $2\times 2\times 26$. I will see you if can finish the rest.

This type of counting is called the inclusion exclusion principle, or in and out method.

Comment: With the combination $AABB*$ you mentioned last wouldn't I actually need to add $2*2*26-1$ back in so one less, because I want to count it once?

Comment: Sorry, I meant subtract once, because if I add them all back in then I havent actually subtracted it once from the total possible combinations.

Comment: No. You would be correct if one thing was subtracted $2\times 2\times 26$ times, so you need to add it back in $2\times 2\times 26-1$ times. But this is not the case. Instead, there are $2\times 2\times 26$ things, such as `ORIFX` and `IFIFQ`, each of which was subtracted twice. Each of these $2\times 2\times 26$ things needs to be added back in once, so they are all now subtracted once. That is why you add in $2\times 2\times 26$. $\tag*{}$ To be crystal clear, for example, `O R I F X` was subtracted once by `O R _ _ _`, and once by `_ _ I F _`.